# kendoPopup() not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

i try to display a popup window like kendo grid's data editing popup. The popup should open upon a button click. i added

```
<div id="popup"><div>content</div></div>
```

to my html and tried to use

```
$("#popup").kendoPopup({
               animation: {
                     close: {
                         effects: "fadeOut zoom:out",
                         duration: 300
                     },
                     open: {
                         effects: "fadeIn zoom:in",
                         duration: 300
                     }
                }
 });
```

but when i call kendoWindow() nothing happened, i would appreciate if you point out what im doing wrong or show a running example of kendoPopup() in a js fidde, as far as i searched there is no working example on internet.

Comment: Thanks for providing your code but this code is not enough to identify your issue. So it would be nice if you can provide some more code. (event code where you trying to open the given kendo window).

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open it like that:

```
$("#popup").data("kendoPopup").open();
```

Here is a working example in Telerik dojo:

http://dojo.telerik.com/IZAzE

Comment: Thank you in telerik demo it does not say this suprisingly :)